# Undefined variable plus using isset and error again

Tags: php

I have this little code . It gets 3 values in HTML and should echo them with 1 function.
But i see Errors ! And i don't know what the problem is .

The Error :

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for dates(), called in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 20 and defined in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for dates(), called in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 20 and defined in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for dates(), called in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 20 and defined in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: hafte in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: rooz in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: mah in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 18

Code :

```
<form method="POST" name="my">
<input type="text" name="hafte"><br>
<input type="text" name="rooz"><br>
<input type="text" name="mah"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['hafte'])){
$hafte = $_POST['hafte'];
}
if (isset($_POST['rooz'])){
$rooz = $_POST['rooz'];
}
if (isset($_POST['mah'])){
$mah = $_POST['mah'];
}
function dates($hafte,$rooz,$mah) {
    echo $hafte." ye ".$rooz." ye ".$mah;
}
dates();
?>
```

Comment: In that case the 3 variables are never defined, so `$_POST` is never defined. How are you posting this form?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, like, seriously? Please read the error messages again. You're not passing the required arguments to `dates();`

Comment: The call to `dates();` passes no arguments to `function dates($hafte,$rooz,$mah)` which - by its definition - requires three arguments.... this is pretty much PHP 101, suggest you read about [function arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).... we're here to help with problems, but we're not an alternative to teaching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your function with argument   like

```
function dates($hafte,$rooz,$mah) {
    echo $hafte." ye ".$rooz." ye ".$mah;
}
dates($hafte,$rooz,$mah);
```

Comment: thanks, and 1 little problem. in opening the page at firs i have errors again, How to solve that ? ** Notice: Undefined variable: rooz in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\test\index.php on line 20**

Comment: Do a checking before your conditions like if($_POST) and wrap others inside it. I think this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that whenever you load the page, it executes also the PHP code for form handling.

You wan't to have a two stage approach:

First display the form

Second handle the processed form.

Something like this

```
    if(!isset($_POST['hafte'])) {
?>
<form method="POST" name="my">
<input type="text" name="hafte"><br>
<input type="text" name="rooz"><br>
<input type="text" name="mah"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
     <?php
       } else {
       // the code to handle the form 
      }
```

And yes, you are not passing any arguments to dates. Is there a point to actually define the function? Why not jut echo $hafte." ye ".$rooz." ye ".$mah;

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" name="my">
<input type="text" name="hafte"><br>
<input type="text" name="rooz"><br>
<input type="text" name="mah"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $hafte = $_POST['hafte'];   
    $rooz = $_POST['rooz'];
    $mah = $_POST['mah'];
    dates($hafte,$rooz,$mah);
}

function dates($hafte,$rooz,$mah) {
    echo $hafte." ye ".$rooz." ye ".$mah;
}

?>
try this.
```